# Half Screen Sidebar Corrections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

Just had a question about my code, I am creating two pop ups that take up half of each screen. I am fairly new to JavaScript and jQuery so I wanted to make sure I am doing it right. Is there a way I can have left side slide out from the left and right side slide out from the right when clicked. Also if you see anything I can improve on please let me know.

HTML

```
<div class="main-menu">
  <a class="contact-btn" href="#">Contact</a>
  <a class="menu-btn" href="#">Menu</a>
  <div class="split left-side">
    <h1>Contact Form</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="split right-side">
    <div id="nav-outer">
        <div id="mobile-menu"></div><!-- end #mobile-menu -->
        <div id="topnav">
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
        </div><!-- end #topnav -->
    </div><!-- #nav-outer -->
    <div class="logo-sidebar">
      <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/logo.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
  $('.right-side').hide();
  $('.left-side').hide();
  $('.menu-btn').click(function(){
    $('.right-side').slideToggle('slow', function(){});

  });
  $('.contact-btn').click(function(){
    $('.left-side').slideToggle('slow', function(){});
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at CSS animations and/or Jquery animations.

Here is a short explanation:
First of all, you want to use some CSS to hide your containers. For this example, I assume that we have only one container. So this container takes up 50% of the screen and must, therefore, be hidden on the left or right side of the screen. This could be done by `position: absolute` or `position: relative;` or whatever suits you best.
This will be the very short JQuery code:

```
$(".slide").click(function(){
    $("div").animate({left: '0px'}, 1000);
});
```

The `1000` is the animation duration which is 1 second in this case.
Now do the same for the right site.
I hope that gives you a basic understanding:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
    $("div").animate({left: '0px'}, 1000);
});
```

```css
div {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: -200px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<button>click</button>
```

as an alternative, you could take a look at the JQuery-UI sliders but I recommend you to solve all your issues with "normal" JQuery until you got a good understanding of how JQuery works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the jquery ui [slide effect](https://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/).

```js
$('.right-side').hide();
$('.left-side').hide();
$('.menu-btn').click(function() {
  $('.right-side').toggle('slide', {direction: 'right'});
});
$('.contact-btn').click(function() {
  $('.left-side').toggle('slide', {direction: 'left'});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="main-menu">
  <a class="contact-btn" href="#">Contact</a>
  <a class="menu-btn" href="#">Menu</a>
  <div class="split left-side">
    <h1>Contact Form</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="split right-side">
    <h1>Menu</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```